# For loops and dataframes, solving differential equation in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, ode

I am having trouble understanding for loops in R.
I want to kind of manually solve the equation "exp(k*x)=k*(x-t)+1" for x. I can't just get x on the left side of the equation alone, so I used ode to get numeric values for exp(k*x). I have estimates for the values of k and t.

```
library(deSolve)
library(graphics)
#estimated parameter value for k
k<-0.1
#function with ODE system
charnov_intercept=function(t,x,parameters){
  A=parameters[1];
  k=parameters[2];
  traveltime=parameters[3];
  odeVec=rep(0,1);
  odeVec[1]=k*(x[1]-t)+1;
  return(list(odeVec))
}
#give numeric values for exp(k*x) 
numsol_expkT<-lsoda(y=c(0.1),times=seq(0,50,by=0.2),func=charnov_intercept,parms=c(30,0.1,-41))
df<-data.frame(numsol_expkT)
```

Now I would like to manually solve for x. I want to use a for loop applying ln(exp(k*x), these are the values that should be in df$X1 now) and then dividing this by k to obtain my values for x.
I would like to put all of these into new columns in my dataframe.

```
#ln 
numsol_kT<-vector("double",ncol(df))
for(i in df$X1){
  numsol_kT[i]<-log(i) #achtung, log ist hier nicht log, sondern tatsächlich ln
  print(numsol_kT)
}
```

This doesn't work, however. R gives me 64 instead of 251 values. I'm brand new at R and have never worked with for loops or anything more than plots before, so I figure I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here.
The rest of the code goes:

```
#put vector as new col in df
df$numsol_kT<-numsol_kT[[2]]

#divide by k and save as new column
for(i in numsol_expkT[,2]){
  numsol_kT[i]<-log(numsol_expkT[i,2])
  print(numsol_kT)
}
df$Tpred_t<-numsol_kT[[2]]
```

I'm still at the very beginning, but if this doesn't work I can't really continue working on it.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcomen to Stackoverflow. For your first loop, try `for(i in 1:length(df$X1)) {numsol_kT[i] <- log(df$X1[i])}` , `length(numsol_kT)
[1] 251`. At least I don't think you want log(i), where i,  in for, is an integer count (of 64, for your code).  I don't really know what expected values here are,...

Comment: As the question stands it makes little sense to me, can you clarify your train of thought? The equation you ask about is not an ODE. It's also not clear what the data frame and loop are supposed to do. If it's just about getting x it's the wrong aproach - you would need to use something called Lambert W.

Answer (score 0):

Imagining I know nothing about the expected values here and picking up from numsol_expkT:

```
#give numeric values for exp(k*x) 
numsol_expkT<-lsoda(y=c(0.1),times=seq(0,50,by=0.2),func=charnov_intercept,parms=c(30,0.1,-41))
df<-data.frame(numsol_expkT)
head(df)
  time        X1
1  0.0 0.1000000
2  0.2 0.3020202
3  0.4 0.5040812
4  0.6 0.7061839
5  0.8 0.9083289
6  1.0 1.1105173

ncol(df)
[1] 2
> nrow(df)
[1] 251
```

it is likely we now want `nrow` not `ncol` for numsol_kT

```
numsol_kT<-vector("double",nrow(df))
for(i in 1:length(df$X1)){
  numsol_kT[i]<-log(df$X1[i]) 
  
} 
str(numsol_kT)
 num [1:251] -2.3026 -1.1973 -0.685 -0.3479 -0.0961 ...
df$numsol_kT <- numsol_kT

head(df)
  time        X1   numsol_kT
1  0.0 0.1000000 -2.30258509
2  0.2 0.3020202 -1.19726137
3  0.4 0.5040812 -0.68501788
4  0.6 0.7061839 -0.34787964
```

we can make a new receiver in df for next loop, made outside the loop as you did, but in this case a new df column

```
df$Tpred_t <- NA
for (i in 1:length(numsol_expkT[,2])) {
+ df$Tpred_t[i] <- log(numsol_expkT[i,2])
+ }
> head(df)
  time        X1   numsol_kT     Tpred_t
1  0.0 0.1000000 -2.30258509 -2.30258509
2  0.2 0.3020202 -1.19726137 -1.19726137
3  0.4 0.5040812 -0.68501788 -0.68501788
4  0.6 0.7061839 -0.34787964 -0.34787964
5  0.8 0.9083289 -0.09614875 -0.09614875
6  1.0 1.1105173  0.10482592  0.10482592
```

And as said, this is just about loop mechanics, not resultant values as I don't know what those should be. `for` is a counter, `i` is the count, `1:length(` both where are we starting to count and how much.
You have to initialize 'receivers' outside the loop, as it is it's own environment, and gone when done, and you did initialize your receivers outside the loop (vector).